# Creating Gradient Brush along a Circular Path

Tags: c#, wpf, gradient

I need to create a multi-step gradient along a circular path, as demonstrated in the following image:

[image: Wheel Gradient]

Does anyone have any ideas on how this could be accomplished in XAML rather than code? Would it be possible to use the existing gradient brushes or composite them somehow to achieve this effect?

Comment: Why the color choices? It's not consistent with any pitch-color mapping I've seen before, and synesthesics [tend to perceive this quite differently](http://rhythmiclight.com/archives/ideas/colorscales.html) anyway. You also don't appear to match the [Color Piano Project](http://colorpiano.com/) exactly.

Comment: The color choices are arbitrary and chosen for aesthetic reasons only. There is no correlation to pitch.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can get a cross-radial effect by using a non-affine transformation such as a perspective transform.  I used the ideas in this article by Charles Petzold:

- [Non-Affine Transforms in 2D?](http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2007/08/250638.html)

to create a XAML-only annular region with a cross-radial gradient.  Here is the markup:

```
<Canvas x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Canvas.Resources>
        <x:Array x:Key="sampleData" Type="sys:Object">
            <x:Array Type="sys:Object">
                <sys:Double>0</sys:Double>
                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset="0.5"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="Blue" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </x:Array>
            <x:Array Type="sys:Object">
                <sys:Double>90</sys:Double>
                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="Blue" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="Green" Offset="0.5"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </x:Array>
            <x:Array Type="sys:Object">
                <sys:Double>180</sys:Double>
                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset="0.5"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="Blue" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </x:Array>
            <x:Array Type="sys:Object">
                <sys:Double>270</sys:Double>
                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="Blue" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="Green" Offset="0.5"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </x:Array>
        </x:Array>
    </Canvas.Resources>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{StaticResource sampleData}">
        <ItemsControl.OpacityMask>
            <RadialGradientBrush>
                <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="0.95"/>
                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.949"/>
                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.501"/>
                <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="0.5"/>
            </RadialGradientBrush>
        </ItemsControl.OpacityMask>
        <ItemsControl.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ItemsControl">
                <ItemsPresenter/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.Template>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Canvas Width="1" Height="1">
                    <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                        <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding [0]}" CenterX="124" CenterY="124"/>
                    </Canvas.RenderTransform>
                    <Viewport3D Width="250" Height="250">
                        <ModelVisual3D>
                            <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                                <Model3DGroup>
                                    <GeometryModel3D>
                                        <GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                                            <MeshGeometry3D Positions="0 0 0, 0 1 0, 1 0 0, 1 1 0" TextureCoordinates="0 1, 0 0, 1 1, 1 0" TriangleIndices="0 2 1, 2 3 1"/>
                                        </GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                                        <GeometryModel3D.Material>
                                            <DiffuseMaterial Brush="{Binding [1]}"/>
                                        </GeometryModel3D.Material>
                                        <GeometryModel3D.Transform>
                                            <MatrixTransform3D Matrix="0.002,0,0,0,-0.499,-0.498,0,-0.998,0,0,1,0,0.499,0.5,0,1"/>
                                        </GeometryModel3D.Transform>
                                    </GeometryModel3D>
                                    <AmbientLight Color="White" />
                                </Model3DGroup>
                            </ModelVisual3D.Content>
                        </ModelVisual3D>
                        <Viewport3D.Camera>
                            <OrthographicCamera Position="0.5 0.5 1" LookDirection="0 0 -1" UpDirection="0 1 0" Width="1"/>
                        </Viewport3D.Camera>
                    </Viewport3D>
                </Canvas>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Canvas>
```

and here is the visual result:

[image]

The effect uses a data source collection with items that have two properties, an angle and a brush.  It draw four quadrants (up, right, down and left) using a different brush for each quadrant.  Then the whole thing is clipped to the annular region with an opacity mask.

Comment: This looks really good to me, but how does the Tuple class look-- just adding a few properties to it and my mark-up throws errors like "Tuple" class does not support direct content, etc.

Comment: I ended up setting up the Tuples in code rather than in mark-up (still curious as to what that class looks like), and this appears to be just what I need. Thanks for a really clever solution, Rick. :)

Comment: I wish there was a standard class like my `Tuple` utility container just for organizing sample data without having to define classes.  You can use an x:Array of x:Arrays or your own data structures.  I'll update the example to use the former method.

Comment: For anyone who is getting small gaps between segments when animating this, I changed the `MeshGeometry3D Positions` to "0 0 0, 0 1.05 0, 1.05 0 0, 1.05 1.05 0" and it looks great.

Answer (score 1):

In GDI+/Winforms you can use the `PathGradientBrush` to do this:

- https://web.archive.org/web/20140906083853/http://bobpowell.net/pgb.aspx
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.pathgradientbrush

Unfortunately there is no support for a PathGradientBrush in WPF, but a few people have asked for it here:

http://dotnet.uservoice.com/forums/40583-wpf-feature-suggestions/suggestions/480949-add-a-pathgradientbrush-like-in-winforms-

(might be worth casting your vote too!)

Because of the lack of support you cannot do it directly in XAML, you could however use GDI+ code to create an image and then use the image in your XAML. This might give you better performance than using a non-affine transformation.

Comment: Try [Charles Petzold's GradientPath](http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2009/02/Graphical-Paths-with-Gradient-Colors.html).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Shazzam](http://www.shazzam-tool.com) You could write a pixelshader that renders this gradient.

I think that in the long run this will be easier than combining linear gradients. An other option is to simply draw a bitmap and use it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but a pixel shader seems like overkill for this scenario-- why write C/HLSL when I could just write some C# code to accomplish this more directly? But my real goal was to see if it could be done in XAML.

Comment: As you can see (Rick Sladkey's answer) it can be done however, I do think that his solution (3D transformations) will be a lot slower and the code for the pixelshader would be much compact.