# How to get this WPF RadialGradientBrush?

Tags: wpf, xaml, gradient

I am trying to achieve the XAML gradient brush like in the picture below. I tried many forms of RadialGradientBrush but no luck. How can I achieve this effect?

[image]

Comment: It sounds like what you want may be a [linear gradient brush, and then transforming the area you're painting with it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4841514/424129).